# Join two lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to interface with pyqt, and I can't just put `zip (relleno, form_label)` due to the fact that later I have:

```
def text_file(self):
    filename = f"{' '.join(self.radio_value())}.txt"
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        f.write(" ".join(self.clickconector()))
        return f
```

If I do it the way previously said, I get an error: `TypeError: can only join an iterable`

`relleno` and  `form_label` are lists both with 11 elements. I wanted to put them together and make one of 11x2, with `form_label` being column 1 and `relleno` column 2, but it only gives me the first element of both. Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

```
def clickconector (self):
    relleno = [self.bitacora.text(), self.turno.text(), self.asesor.text(), self.item.text(), self.modelo.text(), self.identificacion.text(), self.rig.text(),self.horometro.text(),self.condicion.text(),self.orden.text(), self.observacion.text()]
    form_label = ["bitacora", 'turno', 'asesor', 'item', 'modelo', 'identificacion', 'rig', 'horometro', 'condicion', 'orden', 'observacion']
    for a,b in zip (form_label, relleno):
        return a,b
```

Comment: What do you think `return` does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you break for loop with return after first iteration, as [@julien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4565947/julien) pointed out. How do you fix it depends on what you need from function.